# NSHTTPCookie: loop through all keys

Tags: ios, loops, cookies

I have an `NSHTTPCookie` object that contains the following:

```
<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"laravel_session" value:"sdffds" expiresDate:2013-12-10 09:13:21 +0000 created:2013-12-10 07:13:22 +0000 (4.08352e+08) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:"test.domain.com" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> apns_token:(null)>
```

I can get individual element using

```
[cookie valueForKey:@"domain"]
```

How do I loop though all the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
for (id key in cookie.properties.allKeys) {
  NSLog(@"%@", [cookie.properties objectForKey:key]);
}
```